# How to make the current children list item active with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create `slideDown()` and `SlideUp()` effects on my list items. I want to make an effect. when I clicked on the current `<li></li>`, it slides down its inner `<ol></ol>`. while the other list items slides up.

I was trying  the following code available in [here.](https://jsfiddle.net/pu5pj06a/1/)

```
$('#unOrderedLists .itemsListsCategory').on('click', function(){
$(this).children('.innerOrderLists').slideDown().end()
.next('.innerOrderLists').slideUp();
});
```

Comment: [`$(this).children('.innerOrderLists').slideDown().end()
        .siblings('.itemsListsCategory').find('.innerOrderLists').slideUp();`](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/pu5pj06a/2/)

Comment: Please include your relevant code in the actual question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you were after?

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pu5pj06a/6/)

```
$('#unOrderedLists .itemsListsCategory').on('click', function(){
$(this).siblings().children('ol').slideUp();
$(this).children('.innerOrderLists').slideDown();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```
$('#unOrderedLists .itemsListsCategory').on('click', function(){
    $(this).children('.innerOrderLists').slideDown();
    $('#unOrderedLists.itemsListsCategory').not($(this)).children('.innerOrderLists').slideUp();
});
```